# How are modern fighters cleaned?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, fighter

I found this photo of a fighter jet being cleaned, how does this process work?

[image]([usatoday.com](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2017/01/27/defense-secretary-targets-costly-f-35-air-force-one-programs/97140748/))

Comment: You squirt water at it and the water removes the dirt? That can't be what you're asking, because it's obvious. So what are you asking?

Comment: Related gallery: [Wash rack at Eglin AFB](http://www.eglin.af.mil/News/Photos/igphoto/2000242883/). May be removing salt [after flight over ocean](https://www.defense.gov/Photos/Photo-Gallery/igphoto/2001187464/).

Comment: The photo above may also be a demonstration of a chemical weapons purge in case of a CBR attack on a base or aircraft operating in the area.

Comment: The squirting part, obvious.  Less obvious: Are chemicals (surfactants, etc.) added to the water?  Do any precautions need to be taken to keep the water out of places it should not go?  Is the plane taxied through the wash, or is it powered off?  Are there different types of wash for different purposes?

Comment: @DavidRicherby obviously it’s about the procedure, not how water washes dirt away. Is the aircraft taxied through the spray or parked and powered down? Does the aircraft need prepping to prevent water getting into unwanted places etc.

Comment: The F-35 in the picture isn't being washed.  Fighters are still handwashed in a washrack.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they use a chemical to clean aircraft. Back when I was in the Air Force, we used PD-680 type II.

I'm pretty sure they don't use that any more though. PD-680 was discontinued (at least for most applications) around the turn of the century. Most applications that used to use PD-680 switched to PRF-680. I can't guarantee it, but I'd guess that's what they use to clean aircraft.